# SwiftUI - Navigation bar colour change not being applied to status bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationlink

I have the following:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                 Text("Hello")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Edit Profile", displayMode: .inline)
             .background(NavigationConfiguration { nc in
                 nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
                 nc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
            })
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}
```

For the configuration of the nav bar i have:

```
struct NavigationConfiguration: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var configuration: (UINavigationController) -> Void = { _ in }
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationConfiguration>) -> UIViewController {
        UIViewController()
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationConfiguration>) {
        if let nc = uiViewController.navigationController {
            self.configuration(nc)
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason the top status bar is being left out and the colour is not being applied to it:

[image: Status bar image]

How can the red colour also be applied to the status bar above the nav bar, I want it to be the same colour.

I've tried the below, but this fails:

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following (it should work, at least as tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4, but someone reported it was not, so it might be dependent)

[image: demo]

```
init() {
       let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
       navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
       navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed

       UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Comment: Does this only affect the current view na bar or does it affect all nav bars in app?

Comment: @DiNerd This seems to be applied to all nav bars, but this solution hasn't worked

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT 1:**
Checkout my new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031788/8023700
It has detailed description and screenshot as well.

Try using this modifier as this gives you freedom to change color based on each view.

```
struct NavigationBarModifier: ViewModifier {

var backgroundColor: UIColor = .clear

init(backgroundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor = .white) {
    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    
    let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    coloredAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = coloredAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor
}

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    ZStack{
        content
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Color(self.backgroundColor)
                    .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

I used it on below View:

```
struct DummyNavigationView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Page 2")) {
                Text("Go to detail")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Edit Profile", displayMode: .inline)
    }
    .modifier(NavigationBarModifier(backgroundColor: .red, tintColor: .black))
}}
```

Comment: still no luck with that

Comment: @GurmukhSingh can you elaborate on your issue instead of saying no luck. Edit your question with updated code, or provide a link to your project with minimum code.

Comment: Also please can you tell us your Xcode and iOS version